# plot by thick ticks and large fonts of axes number simultaneously

Tags: plotting, fonts, ticks

How I can plot by thick ticks and large fonts of axes numbers simultaneously?

Individually I can do by writing

```
AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick]
```

or

```
TicksStyle -> {{FontSize -> 16, Black}, {FontSize -> 16, Black}}
```

but they doesn't work when I try together in `Plot[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[
 Sin[θ],
 {θ, 0, 2 π},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]